# erb to haml javascript error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I'm trying to migrate from ERB to HAML. However I have a simple javascript function that seems to causing issues. The error that I'm getting when loading the page is `undefined method`name' for nil:NilClass`.

It appears that the line `<% if logged_in %>` is not getting migrated properly and it's still looking for @user even though no one is logged in. How do you set up ruby logic in javascript tags using HAML?

```
# this works
:javascript
  angular.module('userFromServer', [])
    .constant('currentUser', {
      ENV: '#{Rails.env}',
      - if logged_in
        name: '#{@User.name}',
    })

# throws error Unexpected token -
:javascript
  angular.module('userFromServer', [])
    .constant('currentUser', {
      ENV: '#{Rails.env}',
      - if logged_in
        name: '#{@User.name}',
    })
```

Comment: Shouldn't `@User` be `@user`?

Comment: @NickM huh? I don't believe that matters...

Comment: Probably not. I've just never seen an upper-case letter in an instance variable in Rails before and it looked strange to me. Either way, your problem comes from the fact that @User is nil, not from your markup

Comment: @NickM correct, because the `if logged_in` is not evaluating properly so i'm looking for the proper syntax to use an if statement in haml